# Outlook VBA debugger halts with no error

Tags: vba, outlook

I have an outlook macro bound to a key on my keyboard using autohotkey.  When I push `y`, it archives the entire conversation (ala Gmail).  It does this by sending `alt+3` when `y` is pushed.  This runs the 3rd item in the "Quick Access Toolbar", which is the following script:

```
Sub ArchiveConversation()
    Set ArchiveFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Archive")
    If ArchiveFolder Is Nothing Then
          Set ArchiveFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders.Add("Archive")
    End If
    Set oStore = ArchiveFolder.Store
    Set selections = ActiveExplorer.Selection
    If selections.Count <> 0 Then
        For Each theSelection In selections
            Set oConv = theSelection.GetConversation
            If Not (oConv Is Nothing) Then
                 oConv.SetAlwaysMoveToFolder ArchiveFolder, oStore
                 oConv.StopAlwaysMoveToFolder oStore
            End If
        Next theSelection
    Else
        Set oConv = ActiveExplorer.Selection.GetSelection(Outlook.OlSelectionContents.olConversationHeaders).Item(1).GetConversation
        If Not (oConv Is Nothing) Then
             oConv.SetAlwaysMoveToFolder ArchiveFolder, oStore
             oConv.StopAlwaysMoveToFolder oStore
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The script works without a hitch.  However, the first time the script is run after opening outlook, the debugger opens and halts on the first line that starts `Set ArchiveFolder`.  The thing is, there's no error!  All I have to do is hit "run" and the script completes fine.  Stepping over the script verifies no issues with it and the message is archived as expected.  This is really weird.  Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Try stopping, clearing all breakpoints, and restarting outlook. That happened to me once, and I had left a breakpoint before closing.